# How to migrate the create new component from classic home to lightning home page

Tags: lightning-experience, home-page-component

As part of migration from classic to lightning, need to migrate the create new component from classic home page to lighting home page, seems need to create a picklist button in lighting home page.

Am new to lightning, please help me how to do it?

Comment: what does your classic component do on home page?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Global Quick Actions to create a similar functionality for your users with the + menu In Lightning up near Help.

Check out the documentation here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview_global.htm&type=5